# Is it possible to have a Label control with both text and clickable links?

Tags: .net, winforms, hyperlink, label

I need to show a few lines of text with URLs that are formatted as links (i.e. blue, underlined, etc) and load appropriate site in browser when clicked.

Example:

> The first site I strongly recommend is [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and the other is [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

I know I can use a number of `Label` and `LinkLabel` controls but is that the only way? Can it be achieved with a single control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`LinkLabel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.aspx) control for that:

> The LinkLabel control is similar to a Label control with the exception that it can display a hyperlink. Multiple hyperlinks can be specified in the text of the control. Each hyperlink can perform a different task within an application. For example, you can use a hyperlink to display a Web site in Microsoft Internet Explorer or to load a log file associated with an application.

It's a little awkward to use, e.g. IIRC the links are defined using indexes and ranges of the content which makes it a bit complicated with localizable text, but it does what it says on the tin.

Comment: Can you post a code sample that shows `LinkLabel` with example text from my question or something similar? Can a single `LinkLabel` control contain both links **and** text (i.e. Text: [link](http://example.com/) More text: [different link](http://example.org/)?

Comment: Yes a LinkLabel can contain multiple links and also non-link text. There is an example showing several links in a LinkLabel at the linked MSDN page.

Comment: You're right - it is possible and it is very complicated. WinForms links : HTML links - 0 : 10!

Answer (score 0):

Appropriately configured `RichTextBox` control allows to achieve this - change the default values of the following properties:

- set `BorderStyle` to `BorderStyle.None`,
- set `ReadOnly` to `true`,
- set `ScrollBars` to `RichTextBoxScrollBars.None`.

At this point the control will look like a label, but the cursor will change to `IBeam` when hovering over it and the text box will allow to select the text - to avoid this you need to override the following events:

- `SelectionChanged` - unselect text,
- `GotFocus` - return focus to the parent,
- `MouseEnter` - change cursor back to `Cursors.Arrow`.